# Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Ln No-712193'

Tags: vb.net

i am having this error with my vb 2010 code am using access database
i am not able to identify the error please help 
program code is shown ab below

```
Private Sub updateloan()

    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand

    If Not conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        conn.Open()
    End If

    cmd.Connection = conn
    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE tblLoanSetup " & _
                      "SET Loan_no=" & Me.lblloanno.Text &
                      ",ID='" & Me.txtidnumber.Text & "'" & _
                      ",first_name='" & Me.TextFname.Text & "'" & _
                      ",last_name='" & Me.TextLname.Text & "'" & _
                      ",a_date='" & Me.TextDateofLoan.Text & "'" & _
                      ",loan_type= '" & TextLoanType.Text & "'" & _
                      ",loan_amount='" & Me.lblloanrem.Text & "'" & _
                      ",payable_in_months= '" & lblinstbal.Text & "'" & _
                      ",instalments='" & Me.lblpriminst.Text & "'" & _
                      ",interest= '" & TextInterestMonth.Text & "'" & _
                      ",processing_fee='" & Me.lblprocessfee.Text & "'" & _
                      ",available_amount= '" & Me.TextLoanRelease.Text & "'" & _
                      ",available_amount= '" & Me.lblprincln.Text & "'" & _
                      "WHERE tblLoanSetup.ID =" & Me.txtidnumber.Text & ""
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    MessageBox.Show("Successfully Updated")

    ' Me.btnClear.PerformClick()

    conn.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: This is a very bad way of performing SQL queries. First of all it’s very unreadable, and secondly it’s insecure, and in fact enables the most common attack there is: SQL injection. [Use prepared statements instead.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.prepare(v=vs.110).aspx) This will also fix your error, which is a direct consequence of your way of building the query.

Comment: Imagine what would happen if you typed `1234; drop table tblLoanSetup--` in the `lblloanno` textbox?  Do as @KonradRudolph advised and use a parameterized query instead.  It will also likely clear up the problem you are having.

Comment: Thanks guys i get the idea but mine here is an update Querry can i use "UPDATE lending.tblloanSetup (Loan_no, id_no) VALUES (?, ?);"
        command.Parameters.Add("loan_no", OleDbType.Integer, 4)
        command.Parameters.Add("Id_no", OleDbType.Integer, 4)
        command.Parameters(0).Value = "lblloanno.text"
        command.Parameters(1).Value = "lblidno.text"